# Trying to insert a html tag value from a java string

Tags: java, jsp

Trying to find the correct way to insert a string value into a jsp tag from java.  To be specific, the value of the string in java, is the value the tag file path value needs to be.

jsp file:

```
 <img src="<% ... %>" alt="phoneIcon" height="16" width="16">
```

java file:

```
public void iconString(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String phoneIconPath = "file:\\\\e:\\Workspace\\ProjectX\\WebContent\\images\\phone.ico";

        request.setAttribute("phoneIconPath", phoneIconPath);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you hardcoding a file url like that? How do you think that is going to work on the web?

Comment: its not actually going to work like this. this is just an example.  I want to hide alot of information by saving it to a db. and java will pull the values and then insert them into the jsp.

Comment: Well, it's hard to say what you want exactly; but, as posted, change `<% ... %>` (that is `img src=""`) to `<%= request.getAttribute("phoneIconPath") %>`. **But**, I would prefer JSTL and `${requestScope.phoneIconPath}`